# Database modeling: key-value pairs in table

Tags: sql, relational-database

If there's a collection of object (say employee) with a list of a attributes (first name, last name, middle name, dept, etc), and it needs to be modeled in a rdms table as one key/value pair per row, multiple rows per employee. Eg: the table as 3 columns: EmployeeID,FieldName,FieldValue.

For those fields that are optional (eg Middle Name), is it better skip that row all toeghet, or populate it with NULL as the FieldValue column?

I feel skipping it saves space, but having it as NULL is cleaner as it guarantees the same number of rows per employee.

Which one is the more common pattern?

Comment: The most common pattern is using tables with all the needed informations (id, first name, last name, etc...) on each columns, rather than a 3 columns table with id - field name - field value. I never saw such pattern and doubt about its perfs and the ease to maintain its integrity

Comment: @Cid yes agreed. But my question is that GIVEN the above pattern, what is the most common thing to do.

Comment: Check Gordon's answer, it makes sense

Comment: You should consider using JSON if your DBMS supports it.

Comment: "modeled in a rdms table as one key/value pair per row" is an anti-pattern, EAV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to fill in the values, you might as well use a well-defined table.  So, don't put `NULL` values in just because you don't have them.

The advantage of an entity-key-value model, is that you can readily add new keys -- and not have to affect the other entities that don't have those keys.

In such a model, I would say that a `NULL` value for "Middle Name" is different from a missing "Middle Name":

- The `NULL` value means that the middle name was requested but not provided -- essentially, "I have a middle name but won't tell you."
- A missing row with "Middle Name" means essentially that we don't care about the middle name for this entity (it's a corporation not a person).

Comment: What if an employee has no middle name?

Comment: @user1008636 . . . Then you would have no attribute for "Middle Name".  It doesn't apply.